# Retrieving json data which in C#

Tags: c#, json, linq, visual-studio, json.net

I want to deserialise the following Json. I have tried the following:

JSON Data:

```
{
  "data":[
  {
      "employee":[
      {
          "empdetails":[
          {
              "empid":"40",
              "empname":"Amit",
              "empdept":"Director",
              "empphone":[
              {
                  "home":"23432235",
                  "office":"2352353",
              }]
          },
          {
              "empid":"54",
              "empname":"Abhishek",
              "empdept":"HR",
             "empphone":[
              {
                  "home":"5445457",
                  "office":"34634634",
              }]
          },
          {
              "empid":"80",
              "empname":"Rahul",
              "empdept":"Finance"
          },
          {
              "empid":"71",
              "empname":"Anand",
              "empdept":"Marketing",
             "empphone":[
              {
                  "home":"46346346",
                  "office":"346346346",
              }]
          }]
      }],
}
```

Code:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.linq;
using System.Collections.Generics;

class Program
{
public class emp
{
public int empid {get; set;}
public string empname {get; set;}
public string empdept {get; set;}
public string empcontact {get; set; }
}
static void main(string[] args)
{
WebClient c= new WebClient();
var json = c.DownloadString(new uri("sampleurl"));
dynamic dynamicObj=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var data in dynamicObj.data)
{
foreach (var getempdet in data.employee)
{
foreach(var dat in getempdet)
{
foreach(var datas in dat)
{
foreach(var getempdetails in datas)
{
foreach(var finaldata in getempdetails)
{
Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", finaldata);
List<emp> empList=newList<emp>();
}
}
}
}
}
}
Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

Comment: How does this not work? What error are you getting? Looking at it, I'm not so sure it even compiles.

Comment: Create a C# class and Deserialise to that instead of to a `dynamic`.

Comment: i want to know how can i use some other method so as to save the retrieved record in a list and remove the foreach loops from the above program.

Comment: How about providing a valid json? http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create C# classes that map to your `json`. As below:

```
public class Data
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public List<EmpDetails> EmpDetailss { get; set; }
}

public class EmpDetails
{
    public int Empid { get; set; }
    public string Empname { get; set; }
    public string Empdept { get; set; }
    public EmpPhone EmpPhone{ get; set; }
}

public class EmpPhone
{
    public string Home { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
var json = c.DownloadString("sampleurl");
Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

Comment: when i execute the above code it shows two errors: The type or namespace name 'uri' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 2: Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); Cannot explicitly convert type 'object' to JSON_DATA.Program.Data' an explicit conversion exists are you missing a cast?.... why are these error showing up.. please check and thanks for the above help....

Comment: Thanks Sam... Can you tell me how to print the data or get it in a variable, and i have to save only some data in a list not all json data based on criteria such as (emp id = 40) how it can be implemented.